# Javascript Function for rounding values using a Loop.. Callback?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, if-statement, callback

*Have 2 HTML dropdowns, one for 12-hour time, and one for 5-minute intervals on the hour..*

```
..
<select class="form-control" name="hour" id="hour">
  <option>1</option>
  ..
  <option>12</option>
</select>
..
<select class="form-control" name="minute" id="minute">
  <option>0</option>
  ..
  <option>55</option>
</select>
..
```

**Have been trying to write a javascript function inside of another function (that does stuff) using if/elseif to round the values, but it needs help.. Maybe a Callback or Anonymous function?**

```
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();

function hour(hours)
{
    // account for 24-hour clock
    if (hours > 12)
    {
        hours = hours - 12
    };

    // account for 0 in 24
    else if (hours == 0)
    {
        hours = 12
    };
}

// round to the 5minute marks
if (minutes >= 0 && minutes < 3) {minutes = 0};
else if (minutes >= 3 && minutes < 8) {minutes = 5};
..
else if (minutes >= 53 && minutes < 58) {minutes = 55};

// round 58/59/60 to the next hour
else (minutes >= 58 && minutes < 60) {minutes = 0 && hours = hours + 1};

// apply the rounded numbers
$('#hour').val(hours);
$('#minute').val(minutes);
```

Comment: so what is the problem

Comment: it will be great if you can share a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Tip: `function hour(h){return h%12}`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SL8Ba/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny the code is neat, and advanced.. Could you describe the syntax a bit?

Comment: That code does the same as the one I put, just in fewer lines

Comment: Cool, thanks juvian.. Your code is great. @ArunPJohny, am impressed, just not entirely sure how to implement it

Comment: @elclanrs nice function, thanks for that

Comment: @ArunPJohny got it now, thanks for the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tip: Better way for rounding minutes instead of a lot of if/else if:

```
var offset=minutes%5;
if(offset < 3) minutes=minutes-offset;
if(offset >=3) minutes = minutes+(5-offset);
if(minutes==60){
   minutes=0;hours+=1;
}
```